# Django-tables2 - can I pass a queryset filtered using values_list() and distinct() to my table?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to pass a queryset to my table, but I want unique values for a set of fields. How can I use values_list().distinct() to obtain unique values for my fields, and pass this to the queryset of django-tables2?

tables.py

```
class JobTaxonLocationTable(tables.Table):

    result1 = tables.Column(
        accessor='JobResult.result1',
        verbose_name='Result1')

    result2 = tables.Column(
        accessor='JobResult.result2',
        verbose_name='Result2')


class ViewJob(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):

    model = Model1
    table_class = MyTable

    def get_table_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ ViewJob get_table_data request """
        print('>get_table_data')

        # get job_obj from kwargs
        job_obj = Job.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

        if job_obj:
            self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(job_id=job_obj)

            # *at this point I want to restrain my object_list on unique values of result1, result2 - but
            self.object_list = self.object_list.values_list(
                    "result_id__result1",
                    "result_id__result2",
                ).distinct()

            return self.object_list

        else:
            return MyTable.objects.none()
```

The self.object_list is now a values_list queryset so no data is now passed to django-tables2 table. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - used values() instead as it returns a key:v

```
        self.object_list = self.object_list.values(
                "result_id__result1",
                "result_id__result2",
            ).distinct()

result1 = tables.Column(
    accessor='result_id__result1',
    verbose_name='Result 1')
```